# Inserting encrypted field value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL database that has user table. I want to insert a new row for a new user but the password is Base 64 encrypted. How can I insert a new row with encrypted password?

Tried this query:

```
insert INTO users             
(name, regId, address, city, created_at, modify_at, image, mobile, status, user_type, email, password) 
VALUES("New User","","","","2016-11-11 17:08:17","2016-11-11 17:08:17","","123456789",1,3,"newuser@gmail.com","pC9bx7sXEbBnBwmXBuWFiHCjPezaUFl4WsgEYuaRDKc");
```

The row gets inserted but when I try to login with this user, get a password error.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh that's not necessary at all given a base64 encoded string.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this without more details about your password checking code. Many current languages and web frameworks have facilities that automate password handling for you and also make it more secure than what you seem to have.

Comment: You need to insert a value that will match the hashing method used by your password checker.

Comment: what is the datatype of password field ??

Comment: datatype is base64